# Расширение makefil-а для g++

Tags: g++, makefile, компиляция, linux

Какое расширение имеет `makefile` в статье [Hadoop Tutorial 2.2 -- Running C++ Programs on Hadoop](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop)?

Comment: @ivan31 Пустое.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, я видел в проекте на с++ Makefile.am. Точно пустое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В статье, о которой идет речь — пустое `(Makefile).`

Answer (score 2):

Вообще то может быть любое. Только тогда make нужно указать имя файла через параметр `-f`. Но так принято, что его нет. Вообще в линуксе расширения файла не имеет никакого значения (в 99% случаев). А [Makefile.am](http://Makefile.am) - это один с файлов "проекта" для настоящего Makefile. Его использует утилита automake (поэтому и am в конце).